# Find user's favorites in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Alfresco 4.2 and trying to find some user's favorites but the webscript that I'm using returns the results only for the current user. The user that I am investigating exists, I am sure.

What should I do? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the webscript call that works:

```
domain.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/people/-me-/favorites
```

Here is the one that doesn't work:

```
domain.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/people/user@tenant.com/favorites
```

and returns the following:

```
{"error":{"statusCode":404,"briefSummary":"04203980 The entity with id: user@tenant.com was not found","stackTrace":"[org.alfresco.rest.api.impl.PeopleImpl.validatePerson(PeopleImpl.java:155)
```

BTW, `/favorite-sites` instead of `/favorites` works for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The 404 is a misleading. Try to use the URL with a non-existing user. This will also return a 404 but the error will be a little bit different. Accessing an exiting user gives

```
The entity with id: existinguser was not found
```

while a non-existing user gives

```
The entity with id: personId is null. was not found
```

The HTTP response status should be 403 if you try got get the favorites of a different user.

You can't access another users favorites because the class `org.alfresco.rest.api.impl.PeopleImpl` checks that the calling user is the same as the user whose favorites are requested. In Alfresco 5.0d the relvant code is:

```
public String validatePerson(String personId, boolean validateIsCurrentUser)
{
    if(personId.equalsIgnoreCase(DEFAULT_USER))
    {
        personId = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser();
    }

    personId = personService.getUserIdentifier(personId);
    if(personId == null)
    {
        // "User " + personId + " does not exist"
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("personId is null.");
    }

    if(validateIsCurrentUser)
    {
        String currentUserId = AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser();
        if(!currentUserId.equalsIgnoreCase(personId))
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(personId);
        }
    }

    return personId;
}
```

Comment: I can search another user's favourite-sites or sites meanwhile I can't look for its favorites. I would like to know the reason behind this. Maybe favorites are very personal :).

Comment: Ask the Alfresco engineers :)